# VPN chain in one machine without VM natively

Tags: encryption, vpn, ip, proxychains, l2tp

Is it any way to make VPN chain in one machine (MAC or WIN) without VM natively (L2TP/IPsec)?

I need this for obtain an extra layer of security.
For example - if one VPN turns off I still have encryption in another chain (maybe this is not the best example, but I think you get the point).

And I want to make it without the help of VM because VM is sometime too slow.